# How to handle all unhandled errors in both sync and async operations in React?

Tags: reactjs

I've spent a bit of time recently trying to find a comprehensive and reliable way of handling errors in React for both sync and async operations. I'm using `React 15.5.4` and `TypeScript 2.4.1`.

My goal is to catch errors in **sync** and **async** operations(lifecycle methods, event handlers) and display them in a `ErrorDisplay` component that is **the closest parent** of the component that triggered the error.

This is what I have tried but none of the solutions seem to cover all edge cases:

- `unstable_handleError` as per https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2461#issuecomment-311077975 handles only errors in `render`, does not handle errors in event handlers
- custom batch updater as per https://engineering.classdojo.com/blog/2016/12/10/catching-react-errors/, works in production only, doesn't seem to work with event handlers

There is one more approach that I'm planning to try which is to wrap each method at runtime and use React context to pass information re where a given error needs to be displayed. I hesitate a bit to use this approach because React context API is still marked as experimental.

Thoughts?

Comment: Does the new `componentDidCatch` method in React 16 help you out at all? https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html

Comment: As far as I know it only applies to lifecycle methods, so I would still have to come up with something for event handlers.